# How to insert multiple field data with same field name in database with mongoose, nodeJs ( Express )

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to nodejs and I am trying to create a small project for making invoice.
I want to insert products information into mongodb with mongoose and express but i have no idea how to do it.

This is my HTML Code...

```
    <form action="/" method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="product_name" />
        <input type="text" name="description" />
        <input type="number" name="quantity" />
        <input type="number" name="price" />
        <input type="number" name="discount" />
        <input type="number" name="total" />
    </div>
    <div id="product"></div>
</form>
```

This is Script to clone product fileds...

```
<script>
  var addProduct = ()=>{
  var content = document.createElement("div");
  content.innerHTML = `<input type="text" name="product_name" />
    <input type="text" name="description" />
    <input type="number" name="quantity" />
    <input type="number" name="price" />
    <input type="number" name="discount" />
    <input type="number" name="total" />`;
  document.getElementById("product").appendChild(content);
  }
</script>
```

This is route in Express..

```
router.post('/', (req, res)=> { 
console.log(req.body); 
res.redirect('/'); 
})
```

When I submit the form, only one product detail is showing in console like..

```
    {
      product_name: 'Shop',
      description: 'Cinthol',
      quantity: '1',
      price: '30',
      discount: '5',
      total: '25',
}
```

But i need it like this...

```
    "products": {
    "1": {
        "product_name": 'Shop',
        "description": 'Cinthol',
        "quantity": '1',
        "price": '30',
        "discount": '5',
        "total": '25'
    },
    "2": {
        "product_name": 'Shop',
        "description": 'Dettol',
        "quantity": '1',
        "price": '35',
        "discount": '2',
        "total": '33'
    },
}
```

so can you please guide me what should be the HTML code.

Comment: Looks like you need to look at multiple things here.
What does your insert query look like? Does it have a single insert or are you using insertMany (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/).

Comment: If you end up using just one insert in the api (if you follow strict CRUD), are you making multiple api calls from the ui? You may need to make it twice.

Comment: @ronakvp Thanks to comment on this....I will do it in single insert...can you please tell me should i change input attribute name like product[ ], description[ ] same as we do in PHP or is there any other method ? I need req.body data as mentioned above. Rest insert query work i will try to do it my self.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define fields as array,Try This

```
<pre>
<form>
<input type="text" name="product_name[]" />
    <input type="text" name="description[]" />
    <input type="number" name="quantity[]" />
    <input type="number" name="price[]" />
    <input type="number" name="discount[]" />
    <input type="number" name="total[]" />
</form>
</pre>
```